# How to count how many records have minimum value in field? (Django)

Tags: python, django

I have two models `Product` and `Offer`. `Offer` is related to `Product` and contains the `'price'` field. 
I can get min value:
    `Product.objects.get(pk=1).offer_set.aggregate(Min('price'))`

But how can I get how many times does this value occur in the column?

There is my solution:
`Product.objects.get(pk=1).offer_set.values('price').order_by().annotate(Count('‌​price'))` Then I could get the first element from returned list

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this, not tried;

```
from django.db.models import Count

Product.objects.get(pk=1).offer_set.all().values('price').annotate(total=Count('price')).order_by('price')
```